# Initialize object within Hash

Tags: ruby, dry, code-readability

Which way is better? Or do you know more better way?

```
data = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new { |h2, k2| h2[k2] = [] } } # 5 or more times
```

or

```
def object_in_hash(&object)
        Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = object.call() }
end
data = object_in_hash do object_in_hash do [] end end
```

Comment: Please describe what is "better"?

Comment: Alternative "better" - don't use `Hash`, but create dedicated type(class, struct)

Comment: Maybe you want to give a bit of contest, just to understand 'better' to do what?

Comment: @Kodai : Are you trying to implement something similar to _autovivification_ in Perl, i.e. make Hash which automatically creates a new subhash as soon as a key is refered to, which does not exist yet?

Comment: I meant that "better" is "more readable".

Answer (score 0):

You can create an infinitely nested hash by passing its [`default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Hash.html#default_proc-method) to the new instance:

```
data = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }
```

This lets you assign values to arbitrary keys:

```
data[:foo][:bar][:baz] = []
data[:foo][:bar][:qux] = []

data #=> {:foo=>{:bar=>{:baz=>[], :qux=>[]}}}
```